# Peer review problem

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I am trying to edit the answer to my question because the current answer is wrong.

[Automatic redirection to https with port change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899518/automatic-redirection-to-https-with-port-change)

The current answer is window.location.host + :8443 , but in reality is should be hostname instead of host.

host will give me localhost:8080:8443 , while hostname will give me localhost:8443.

When I edited the answer, I clearly stated the reason, but because I do not have enough reputation, the edit was subject to be peer reviewed. Now I check the answer again and my edit did not go through.

I'm not sure if this was a misclick or not, but the answer should be changed to window.location.hostname. Thanks ~

The main problem here is that people are marking the edit as incorrect when in fact the edit was correct. People that don't know the code are judging whether it is correct or not, and that is only causing more problems.

EDIT :

For the record, here is proof that the correct answer should in fact be window.location.hostname instead of window.location.host

[location.host vs location.hostname and cross-browser compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725890/window-location-host-vs-window-location-hostname-and-cross-browser-compatibility)

Comment: You should leave a comment on the post for the error. Edits like these are usually rejected.

Comment: FYI your suggested edit was rejected by 3 reviewers: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3328753

Comment: Do you think the incorrect answer is due to a typo, or is it just a wrong answer?  I think the answer to that question determines the appropriate action

Comment: Why are these edits rejected? Shouldn't peer review know enough to allow the edit or deny it?

Comment: @krikara in short no, there is no guarentee the reviewers will have enough knowledge in the subject matter to judge the technical accuracy of an edit.

Comment: @krikara Don't change the code in an edit - that should be a comment. Edits are for grammar errors, etc.

Comment: Also, why accept an answer if it doesn't work?

Comment: @Bart Then those 3 reviewers don't know JS. 2 People did accept however.

Comment: @LBT The person contributed to me finally getting the right code to work. However, I didn't notice that he had host instead of hostname until after I marked it correct.

Comment: @krikara I don't think anyone is arguing that the answer is correct or not, or that your edit was technically wrong.  All we are saying is the type of edit you made is discouraged.  If the answer is wrong, then a comment explaining why is the correct course of action.  And of course a downvote is also appropriate to if it is really a wrong answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I didn't really state this in my question here, but what I really have a problem with is multiple people marking the edit as incorrect when it is in fact correct. And all I am trying to do is promote the learning experience for entire community, but it is counter productive if people that don't know about the code judge whether an edit to the code is allowed.

Comment: @krikara it depends on your definition of "correct".  You are interpreting it to mean "technically correct" whereas the community general interprets it to mean that the edit was proper.  The edit was not proper according to the community-enforced guidelines, hence it was marked as "incorrect".

Comment: @psubsee2003 He put 2 ports in an address. This is pretty much a typo. It is like putting `http://http://localhost:8080`. This simply does not work and the current answer is just a simple mistake. All I wanted to do was fix it, but people are rejecting it saying my edit is incorrect. If people don't know the correct solution, they should not accept or reject an edit. Instead, they should just let someone else accept or reject an edit. Unless they want to argue that having 2 ports in an address is correct, there should be no reason why they marked my edit as incorrect.

Comment: Many people don't like edits which change code like that. I think it was okay if that's all you changed as it seems like a minor goof, but a comment would work, too.. "Don't you mean 'hostname?'"

Comment: @AndrewBarber So if it was an English typo, it would be fixed and approved. If it is a programming typo, and stated within the reason for the edit, people are inclined to reject the edit regardless of its validity. Instead of autorejecting coding edits, why not put in the rules where people can skip over edits they don't understand? What is the logic in autodeclining possibly correct edits? The only thing that comes out of it is delaying the correct answer.

Comment: @Jeffman Please stop this anti-social behavior, which contradicts the official rules of Stack Exchange as well as its purpose of generating good content. [Editing is a fundamental tool of Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). **Correcting minor mistakes is a function of edits**. Comments are **not** suitable to signal mistakes — that's what edits are for. [Comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) are only for **temporary** issues (for example, if you aren't sure about something, then asking for confirmation in a comment is fine).

Comment: @Jeffman: Did you really just delete those well-reasoned responses of yours (which I for one happen to agree with for the most part) and replace them with a single hostile remark?

Answer (score 5):

Earlier someone made a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204648/allow-proposing-edits-even-if-you-have-the-rep-to-edit-directly) to allow them to propose edits to questions even when they have edit privileges.

My [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204669/182513) there pretty much covers much of the same reasons as to why, but one specific excerpt is very relevant

> A completely peer reviewed editing system doesn't exist in the way you want, and suggested edits are not the way to add the functionality. You are looking for a way to propose a modification to an existing answer and have the the author or several people who are experts in the topic (or at least well versed) look at it and say "Yes, that is an improvement".
>
> It sounds great, but I think you are grossly overvaluing the quality of the review system. In most cases, the reviewer is not going to be well-versed enough in the subject matter to make a judgement (and in many cases, they will have no clue). Likewise, suggested edits that change the answer are often discouraged (partially for this very reason).

You are trying to change an answer to say something completely different than it does now.  A comment is always preferable in these situations.

If it is just a typo, then the author of that answer should be very happy to correct it.  However, if the comment chain is accurate, the author seems to think that his answer should work, as such, you are trying to change his answer to say something he doesn't want to say.  In this case, your own answer with your own solution would be better.

Comment: Normally, the peer review system is fine. But when you have people peer reviewing and rejecting correct code snippets AFTER I state the correct reason why it needs to be edited, then you have a problem. In this scenario, I was changing a wrong answer into a right answer, more than just simply improving it.

Comment: @krikara In this case the answerer clearly didn't feel such a change is appropriate, so rejecting the edit is correct.

Comment: @Servy Actually, the answerer didn't reject it. 2 people accepted it, while 3 others rejected it, so the edit failed. The problem is that the 3 people that rejected either don't know JS, or weren't paying close enough attention to the current answer because the answer is in fact wrong, by what is arguably a typo (writing the port twice in a row is a typo in my book).

Comment: @krikara I know the author didn't reject it, but based on their comments they clearly felt the answer was correct as it stood, and didn't think it should be edited.  Given that, the reviewers were correct to reject the change.  Had it just been a typo then I wouldn't have expected the post author to state, in comments, that he didn't feel the post should be changed.  You suggested the edit because the author *intentionally chose not to edit his post in response to your comment*.  That makes their intentions clear.  If they had intended to post something else, they'd have edited their post.

Comment: @krikara maybe they didn't know JS, maybe they do.  You don't know and I don't know.  But you keep arguing the same point.. "my edit was right".  And both Servy and I and may others are trying to explain that regardless of whether the edit was technically accurate, the community generally does not approve of edits that change answers against the wishes of the original author.

Comment: @Servy Actually, that was not the case. I was originally in chat with the author and he helped me achieve the correct answer. I quickly marked his answer correct without fully reading it. Some hours later, the author is gone, but I figure I can fix the typo in his code. If he was on, he would know it is a typo too. He did not intentionally choose not to edit his post in response to my comment, that was for the href part of his answer, which he did in fact edit out after. If there was timestamp for the comment, people would know it occurred before the edit.

Comment: @krikara 1) This is why you shouldn't accept answers that you haven't even read through.  Wait until you've verified that they solve your problem first.  2) The author specifically said that he tested his solution and it worked, as he wanted, as is.  Clearly your change isn't fixing a typo, it's just making a change the author never considered.  That's something that belongs in a comment, not an edit.  If the author wants to, he can edit his post.  If he doesn't, that is his right.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Alright, I finally get it. The comments make it look like I am changing the answer against the author's wishes. But that is really not the case as the author and I were working towards the correct answer (further revealed in the chat). In this case, however, it really was a simple typo and the author really did deserve the credit for the answer. (His webserver might have auto fixed the double port bug for him, but it didn't autocorrect on my tomcat7) Servy, I still believe it is a typo and he will fix it when he comes back on. We will see then.

Answer (score 3):

Edits are there to help the content that the post's author has provided shine, not to change what that content is.

If this was a clear typo by the author, and they *meant* to type out something else instead then this would be an appropriate edit, but based on the comments, that's not the case, the author is simply wrong (or at least a little bit wrong in a mostly right answer).

You can post a comment with your proposed change to discuss it with the author.  They may change/update their answer based on your comments.

If they choose not to, for whatever reason, and you feel that your change is important enough, and that it's likely to be helpful to future visitors, you can post a separate answer that cites the previous answer for what it has provided but includes the changes you needed to make.  Note that in some of these cases (although this doesn't seem to be the case for you) an answer may simply need tailoring to the specific situation the question asker is in; in such cases the answer isn't wrong, it's just a bit more generalized.  In such cases the answerer may not *want* their answer changed to be tailored to the specifics in the given questionl